# How to grep a portion of file name using grep or sed based on a pattern in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I need to get a portion of file name based on a pattern. The file pattern here is not for checking if the file name matches the pattern exactly.  The "?"s represent dates, so it can be in the format of YYYYMMDD, or YYYY-MM-DD, and I don't want to get the dates. I guess for now, I will just try to get the letter portion before or after the date portion based on the pattern.

For example, if the file name pattern and the actual file name are:

```
 *_???????? and file name: ab_cd_20160505_efg.txt
```

I want to grep the string `ab_cd`. `efg` is skipped because it's not part of the pattern.

If the file pattern and the actual file name are:

```
 ????-??-??_* and file name: 2016-05-05_abc_def-ghi.csv
```

(contain both dash and undercore), I want to grep the string `abc_def-ghi`.  The `.csv` is skipped because we don't care about the file extension, that's why we didn't give `.csv` in the pattern.

So, can someone let me know how to accomplish these using grep or sed or other command in shell script?

Comment: I don't understand the rules.

Comment: I removed the last example in the post.  I guess for now, I will just try to get the letter portion before or after the number portion.

Comment: Where does the pattern come from? Why is `efg` skipped in the first example? What's the rule for characters between question marks? You're asking for some kind of mapping from two strings (pattern plus file name) to one string (your output), but the rules are still not clear to me.

Comment: The pattern comes from user input.  The numbers are dates, so it can be in the format of 20160505, or 2016-05-05.  "efg" is skipped is because we only want letters in front of the date in this case, so we don't give what we don't want in the pattern.

Comment: Why does the second one not include `.csv`?

Comment: Because we don't care about the file extension, that's why we didn't give .csv in the pattern.

Comment: I see. This should all be part of the question. Unless the question is so precise that I can write my own patterns, filenames and expected results, there is no way I can figure out what you want.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't in the pattern, so `*` matches what exactly? Up to the next period? It's apparently not the end of the string.

Comment: I just updated the post

Comment: yeah, I think * matches up to the next period.

Comment: When did the word `pattern` on it's own become acceptable for describing requirements for software? Unless you're talking about knitting or quilt making the word `pattern` is ambiguous and needs to be avoided - [edit] your question to replace the word `pattern` with either `string` or `regexp` or `globbing pattern`, whichever it is you want to use. Without that we don't know what `*` and `?` mean in your example as they mean different things in all 3 contexts. You may THINK you got an answer already but it may only work for your current sample and not actually do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does pretty much the same as [karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37081942/3266847), but in Bash:

```
extract () {
    local pattern="$1"
    local fname="$2"
    pattern="${pattern//\?/[[:digit:]]}"
    pattern="${pattern/\*/([^[:digit:].]+)}"
    [[ $fname =~ $pattern ]]
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
}
```

It uses parameter expansion to build a regex pattern by replacing all the `?` and `*`, then matches the filename against that pattern and the printing the first capture group.

For example, the regex generated from `*_????????` looks like

```
([^[:digit:].]+)_[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]
```

The function can be used like this:

```
$ extract '*_????????' 'ab_cd_20160505_efg.txt'                                                                     
ab_cd
$ extract '????-??-??_*' '2016-05-05_abc_def-ghi.csv'
abc_def-ghi
```

Answer (score 3):

a two step approach

```
$ pattern=$(sed 's/*/([^0-9.]+)/;s/?/[0-9]/g' <<< '*_????????');
$ sed -r "s/$pattern.*/\1/" <<< 'ab_cd_12345678_efg.txt'
ab_cd

$ pattern=$(sed 's/*/([^0-9.]+)/;s/?/[0-9]/g' <<< '????-??-??_*');
$ sed -r "s/$pattern.*/\1/" <<< '1234-56-78_abc_def-ghi.csv'
abc_def-ghi
```

note the double quotes in the second `sed` command to let bash expand the pattern.

Comment: The patterns in the questions also contain `*` which expands to what OP wants to extract, so for example in the first one `_efg.txt` is not wanted, and in the second one apparently the file extension isn't wanted.